# tensorflow tools: can't figure out how to build/run summarize_graph

Tags: tensorflow, coremltools, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert my *.pb tensorflow model to coreML.  I'm getting stuck on identifying my output node of my model.

In order to obtain my output node, I've attempted to build and run summarize_graph on my *.pb file, but running into issues.  How do I build and run summarize_graph after downloading the source?

I've run the following command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph=tensorflow_inception_graph.pb
```

and I get the following error:

> INFO: Analysed 0 targets (0 packages loaded). INFO: Found 0 targets...
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 0.389s, Critical Path: 0.01s INFO: Build completed
>   successfully, 1 total action
>   bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph: No such
>   file or directory

After issuing the bazel command, a blank bazel-bin directory appears in the location I executed the command.

Note, summarize_graph didn't exist in my tensorflow installation. So I downloaded the source from github tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms and copied it into my tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms directory.

the directory contains the following:

> BUILD README.md
>   **init**.py
>   **init**.pyc add_default_attributes.cc add_default_attributes_test.cc backports.cc backports_test.cc compare_graphs.cc
>   fake_quantize_training.cc fake_quantize_training_test.cc file_utils.cc
>   file_utils.h file_utils_test.cc flatten_atrous.cc
>   flatten_atrous_test.cc fold_batch_norms.cc fold_batch_norms_test.cc
>   fold_constants_lib.cc fold_constants_lib.h fold_constants_test.cc
>   fold_old_batch_norms.cc fold_old_batch_norms_test.cc
>   freeze_requantization_ranges.cc freeze_requantization_ranges_test.cc
>   fuse_convolutions.cc fuse_convolutions_test.cc insert_logging.cc
>   insert_logging_test.cc obfuscate_names.cc obfuscate_names_test.cc out
>   python quantize_nodes.cc quantize_nodes_test.cc quantize_weights.cc
>   quantize_weights_test.cc remove_attribute.cc remove_attribute_test.cc
>   remove_device.cc remove_device_test.cc remove_ema.cc
>   remove_ema_test.cc remove_nodes.cc remove_nodes_test.cc
>   rename_attribute.cc rename_attribute_test.cc rename_op.cc
>   rename_op_test.cc round_weights.cc round_weights_test.cc set_device.cc
>   set_device_test.cc sort_by_execution_order.cc
>   sort_by_execution_order_test.cc sparsify_gather.cc
>   sparsify_gather_test.cc strip_unused_nodes.cc
>   strip_unused_nodes_test.cc summarize_graph_main.cc transform_graph.cc
>   transform_graph.h transform_graph_main.cc transform_graph_test.cc
>   transform_utils.cc transform_utils.h transform_utils_test.cc

I'm on a macbook pro

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is running into the similar problem, I solved it.

Navigate to the root of the tensorflow source directory

```
cmd> ./configure
cmd> bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
```

(you may get an error about xcode; if so, run the following)

```
cmd> xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

cmd> bazel clean --expunge

cmd> bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
```

Comment: I'm at `usr/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow` but when I enter the command `./configure`, it says **-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory**

Comment: @Chaine did you find solution for this? I am also using a virtualenv and do not have the environment as needed for bazel builds

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 walkthrough:

```
yum install epel-release
yum update
yum install patch
curl https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/vbatts/bazel/repo/epel-7/vbatts-bazel-epel-7.repo -o /etc/yum.repos.d/vbatts-bazel-epel-7.repo
yum install bazel
curl -L -O https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/v1.8.0.tar.gz
cd tensorflow-1.8.0
./configure  # interactive!
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph
```

Comment: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file